# Mapping function into elements of Sum

Tags: function-construction, summation, attributes

I'm trying to set an attribute that's valid for a generic sum, where n and f are arbitrary.

```
de[A_ + B_] := de[A] + de[B]
de@Sum[f[i], {i, n}]
```

Is this possible?

Simplified example:

```
de[f_[i_], k_] := If[k <= i, f[i], 0]
de[A_ + B_, k_] := de[A, k] + de[B, k]
Simplify[de[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, n}], k], {n \[Element] Integers, k < n}]
```

should output Sum[f[i],{i,k,n}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) is probably the best way to go here:

```
de[A_ + B_] := de[A] + de[B];
de /: de[Sum[q_, α_]] := Sum[de[q], α];

de@Sum[f[i], {i, n}]
(* Sum[de[f[i]], {i, n}] *)
```

Comment: Nice! Also, for the example one can use

Unprotect[Sum]
Sum[de[f[i], k_], {i, 1, \[Alpha]_}] := 
 Sum[de[f[i], k], {i, k, \[Alpha]}]

Though be careful when unprotecting stuff in general not to get some random bugs